# Retrofit Crash After Android Update

Tags: android, retrofit2, okhttp

I am having problems with retrofit and okhttp after updating my Android Studio to the latest version a few days ago. Prior to then my code was working without any issues. Here is the class for the retrofit client and it crashes

```
public class ApiClient {
public static final String BASE_URL = "myapiurl";
private static Retrofit mRetrofit = null;

public static Retrofit getClient() {
    if (mRetrofit ==null) {
        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
                .setLenient()
                .setDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss")
                .create();
            mRetrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
                    .build();
    }
    return mRetrofit;
}
```

}

The error I get is pretty generic and I am at a loss for where to go next.

```
2019-03-03 07:15:15.774 21769-21769/com.instreamwater.app E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.instreamwater.app, PID: 21769
java.lang.BootstrapMethodError: Exception from call site #0 bootstrap method
    at okhttp3.internal.Util.<clinit>(Unknown Source:111)
    at okhttp3.internal.Util.skipLeadingAsciiWhitespace(Unknown Source:0)
    at okhttp3.HttpUrl$Builder.parse(Unknown Source:11)
    at okhttp3.HttpUrl.get(Unknown Source:6)
    at retrofit2.Retrofit$Builder.baseUrl(Unknown Source:5)
    at com.instreamwater.app.network.ApiClient.getClient(Unknown Source:12)
    at com.instreamwater.app.activity.LogInOrSignUpActivity.a(Unknown Source:30)
    at com.instreamwater.app.activity.LogInOrSignUpActivity.a(Unknown Source:0)
    at com.instreamwater.app.activity.LogInOrSignUpActivity$4.onClick(Unknown Source:32)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6597)
    at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:6574)
    at android.view.View.access$3100(View.java:778)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:25885)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: Bootstrap method returned null
    at okhttp3.internal.Util.<clinit>(Unknown Source:111) 
    at okhttp3.internal.Util.skipLeadingAsciiWhitespace(Unknown Source:0) 
    at okhttp3.HttpUrl$Builder.parse(Unknown Source:11) 
    at okhttp3.HttpUrl.get(Unknown Source:6) 
    at retrofit2.Retrofit$Builder.baseUrl(Unknown Source:5) 
    at com.instreamwater.app.network.ApiClient.getClient(Unknown Source:12) 
    at com.instreamwater.app.activity.LogInOrSignUpActivity.a(Unknown Source:30) 
    at com.instreamwater.app.activity.LogInOrSignUpActivity.a(Unknown Source:0) 
    at com.instreamwater.app.activity.LogInOrSignUpActivity$4.onClick(Unknown Source:32) 
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6597) 
    at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:6574) 
    at android.view.View.access$3100(View.java:778) 
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:25885) 
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

`2019-03-03 07:15:15.945 7099-7166/system_process E/InputDispatcher: channel 'b2904e com.instreamwater.app/com.instreamwater.app.activity.LogInOrSignUpActivity (server)'` ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!

Has anyone else experienced this issue recently after Android Studio updates or even in the past and have any suggestions on how to fix this? I am using the latest version like: `implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.5.0'` in `build.gradle`.

Answer (score 8):

For reference, a reproduction of [Jake Wharton's answer](https://github.com/square/retrofit/issues/3043):

> You have updated OkHttp to version 3.13 or newer and [per its release notes](https://github.com/square/okhttp/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#version-3130), OkHttp now requires that you enable Java 8 in your builds to function. You can learn more about how to enable this at https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support.
>
> You need to add something like
>
> ```
> android {
>     compileOptions {
>         targetCompatibility = "8"
>         sourceCompatibility = "8"
>     }
> }
> ```

Answer (score 0):

In case this helps anyone, I posted to the Github project and received an answer [here](https://github.com/square/retrofit/issues/3043) that fixed my issue.

Answer (score -1):

I  add ：

```
     android {
        compileOptions {
            targetCompatibility = "8"
            sourceCompatibility = "8"
        }
}
```

but it does not work,so i migrate my project to AdroidX,and it is really work.

Comment: because  different version of AS